# Can't Access Windows 7 Shared Folders Anymore

Tags: networking, 16.04, windows-7, samba

I accessed Windows 7 Shared Files through the Files System in Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked fine.
But, when I tried again, I can't access Windows Shared Files anymore. I have a message like:
*Failed to recover server shared list - Folder or File not Found* (I am translated from portuguese, and maybe it's not the popup in English).

- In cmd I tried `smbclient -L TDMS-PC -U TDMS` I get "Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL"
- When I ping, I can reach the windows machine and vice versa
- Both Machines have the same network masks
- When I tried `smbclient //192.168.1.23/downloads -U TDMS` I get "protocol negotiation failed: ERRDOS:ERRnomem"

And it worked before (in the Files Manager).

What could be wrong?

Comment: Does this work: https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-7-samba-errnomem.html

Comment: @Morbius1 Thanks! I tried and it worked (I don't know why this problem..., because it worked before without changing the regedit).

But only using the terminal or in File Manager typing smb://ip_windows_machine... If in File Manager (Ubuntu) I click in Network and then in Windows Network, I can't access